# Spark Application as a Rest Service

Tags: apache-spark

I have a question regarding a specific spark application usage.
So I want our Spark application to run as a REST API Server, like Spring Boot Applications, therefore it will  not be a batch process, instead we will load the application and then we want to keep the application live (no call to spark.close()) and to use the application as Realtime query engine via some API which we will define. I am targeting to deploy it to Databricks. Any suggestions will be good.
I have checked Apache Livy, but not sure whether it will be good option or not.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Spark isn't designed to run like this; it has no REST API server frameworks other than the HistoryServer and Worker UI built-in

If you wanted a long-running Spark action, then you could use Spark Streaming and issue actions to it via raw sockets, Kafka, etc. rather than HTTP methods

Comment: I see, so I have limited knowledge about spark streaming, but can I use it like a REST Application (kind of) if I go for spark Streaming ? 

I hope my questions is clear to you.. For example my App do some huge calculations based on some input  then returns a number and closes the session. Now Want I want is , I want to do something like :  I keep supplying input , and it returns me values one by and, provided all the intermediate RDDs are cached when I did executed my 1st query, so that the upcoming queries can be served faster.

Comment: You cannot "use it like REST Application", no since that implies interacting with it over HTTP rather than asynchronous actions via streams

Comment: If you want to keep sessions open and cache results, then Livy is closer to what you want

Comment: okey, I checked Livy once, I found that after submitting a query,they provide Job ID as far I remember, then we need to call other API with that Job ID to get back the result of that operation.

Comment: Right. Because it runs a Spark job and you need to poll to check for completion.

Answer (score 2):

Good question let's discuss step by step

1. You can create it and it's working fine , following is example :

- https://github.com/vaquarkhan/springboot-microservice-apache-spark

2. I am sure you must be thinking to create Dataset or Data frame and keep into memory and use as Cache (Redis,Gemfire etc ) but here is catch

i) If you have data in few 100k then you really not needed Apache Spark power Java app is good to return response really fast.

ii) If you have data in petabyte then loading into memory as dataset or data frame will not help as Apache Spark doesn’t support indexing since Spark is not a data management system but a fast batch data processing engine, and Gemfire you have flexibility to add index to fast retrieval of data.

**Work Around :**

- Using Apache Ignite’s(https://ignite.apache.org/) In-memory indexes (refer Fast
  Apache Spark SQL Queries)
- Using data formats that supports indexing like ORC, Parquet etc.

So Why not use Sparing application with Apache Spark without using spark.close().

1. Spring application as micro service you need other services either on container or PCF/Bluemix/AWS /Azure/GCP etc and Apache Spark has own world and need compute power which is not available on PCF.
2. Spark is not a database so it cannot "store data". It processes data and stores it temporarily in memory, but that's not presistent storage.
3. Once Spark job submit you have to wait results in between you cannot fetch data.

**How to use Spark with Spring application as Rest API call :**

Apache Livy is a service that enables easy interaction with a Spark cluster over a REST interface. It enables easy submission of Spark jobs or snippets of Spark code, synchronous or asynchronous result retrieval, as well as Spark Context management, all via a simple REST interface or an RPC client library.

- https://livy.apache.org/

Comment: Hi , thanks for the reply, actually I need spark for the requirement. My requirement is first we load all items into a DF and then Cache it. Then We run queries on it and get the result. Now problem is, currently its loading , creating DF , calculating, then retunrs the result and then closing it. 
What I want to do is, I want to start the session, keep the DF in memory, and then query the DF with various conditions back to back and get back the result without closing the session. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: You need to complete all calculation before dump data into cache or datastore and your microservice wil hit on index (RDBMS,NOSQL,NewSQl) and return results  , you should not run Spark for individula calculation ,Example  create DF , dedup , transform into new df , add filters then do caluation whatever results back dump into datastore

Comment: actually the situation is , we need to query the cached  DF that is generated after many transformation every time. We are using SANSA framework. Therefore, we are extracting information from RDF Triples and then converting it into a DF , and that DF can contain huge amount of Data, So once the original DF is created and cached on Memory and Disk, we query that DF with different Parameters. So is it possible to query on that DF back to back without closing the session ?

Comment: Yes as I mentioned you can do that ,write spark job and perform all operations